# Retrieve first two fields from the first column

Tags: text-processing

I want to convert this file in Linux...

```
1:a:A:G rs123
1:b:C:T rs456
1:c:G:A,C rs174
```

To this file...

```
1:a rs123
1:b rs456
1:c rs174
```

Would anybody know how to do this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: can someone please tell why he upvoted this? this does not show any effort of the OP what so ever

Comment: If that’s all you want, you can get it with `printf '%s\n' '1:a rs123' '1:b rs456' '1:c rs174'`. If you want a solution that can handle different input, you should describe all the variations that can appear. For example, could you have `1:a:a:G`, `1:A:A:G`, `1:a:A` or `1:c:G:A:C`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing wrong with @terdon solution but just for fun a `gawk` solution using

```
awk -F':[^a-z]+' '{print $1, $2}' file1
```

Composes `IFS` as a contextual `regex` which matches any contiguous string starting `:` followed by a variable length combination of anything except lower case letters `[^a-z]+`, which just leaves you with the two chunks you want.

Comment: Ha! I had never considered that we could use a negated character class in the FS, nice!

Comment: @terdon It's your fault for grabbing the low hanging fruit. Had to find something creative!

Answer (score 5):

If all input values are consistent , then just print all columns except those two :

```
awk -F'[: ]' '{ print $1":"$2"  "$5 }' inputFile
```

Answer (score 4):

A few choices:

```
$ awk -F'[: ]' '{print $1":"$2,$5}' file 
1:a rs123
1:b rs456
1:c rs174
```

This tells `awk` to use either a space or a `:` as the field separator and then to print the first field, a `:`, the second field and the 5th field.

```
$ sed -E 's/^([^:]*:[^:]*):.* (.*)$/\1 \2/' file 
1:a rs123
1:b rs456
1:c rs174
```

Here, `sed` captures any non`-:` (`[^:]*`) from the beginning of the line (`^`) until the first `:` and the next stretch of non-`:` characters until the second `:`. Then, we match everything until the final space of the line and capture any characters after it. Finally, the whole line is replaced by the two captured patterns (`\1 \2`).

```
$ perl -pe 's/(.+?:.+?):.*\s(\S+)$/$1 $2/' file 
1:a rs123
1:b rs456
1:c rs174
```

This is the same basic idea as the sed approach above but uses non-greedy regex patterns and searches for non-whitespace characters after the last whitespace character on the line.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from all the GNU coreutil solutions it would also work if you open it in `vim` and type

```
:%norm 0f:f:vf hd
```

followed by `Enter`.

What it does:

`:` gets you in command mode

`%` modifier to have `norm` run on all lines in the file

`norm` a command that can run on multiple lines and just does as if you typed what ever it is followed by in normal mode.

`0` to get to the beginning of the line

`f:` to go to the next occurence of the colon symbol in the text (i.e. your field seperator. Do this twice to get to the beginning of the 3rd column

`v` to enter visual mode (because that makes selecting the stuff to delete a whole lot easier :-) )

`f˽` (note the space!!) to go to the next occurence of the space (i.e. the other field seperator)
`h` to go one character to the left (so that we do not delete the space when we do delete our selection afterwards) and finally

`d` to delete the selected stuff